# finding screen position when using jScrollPane

Tags: jquery, jscrollpane

I have a list of images contained within jScrollPane and when you click on a image some fancy pants animations occur. The problem is I need to get the location of the image from the top of the screen. I can easily do this with jQuery when not using jScrollPane but when I use location doesn't change. How can I find the location of the image with respect to the movement within jScrollPane?

how I'm building the images.

```
  grid = $('#grid'),
  str = '';

  grid.empty();
  $.each(main_images,function(i,v){
   str += '<li gallery="'+i+'"><div class="title">'+(content.navgrid[2][i].title )+'</div><a ng-href="#" class="zoom"><img src="'+main_images[i]+'"/><span></span></a></li>';
});
  grid.append($(str));

  grid.jScrollPane({hideFocus:true});
```

Comment: A visual image of what you're trying to do would help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I experimented with the Chrome developer tools and this demo:

http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/auto_reinitialise.html

If you open the developer tools and inspect the `<p>` tags that are injected into the pane, you'll see there is an `offsetTop` property on each one.  That might be what you're looking for.